# Rails: two (or more) instances of same collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a `collection_select` instance in a form, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have two or more instances in the same form. They'd be built from the same model, and they would save as if they were checkboxes constructed in an `Article.all.each` loop. To have these work

```
<%= f.collection_select("article_ids", Article.where(:page => 1), :id, :name) %>
<%= f.collection_select("article_ids", Article.where(:page => 2), :id, :name) %>
<%= f.collection_select("article_ids", Article.where(:page => 3), :id, :name) %>
```

in the form is pretty much what I'm after. It's essentially a multiple select but spread over a couple of selects. The field already accepts multiple results, but when I save the form as it is above it only records the option from the final select. Any thoughts?

Cheers!

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like this: `<%= select = f.collection_select(:article_ids, Article.all, :id, :name) %>` and then use just `<%= select %>` wherever else you want to display the same HTML?

Comment: That works to display the select boxes, not to record their separate selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went with checkboxes to solve this, because it's truly the stuff of nightmares.

```
<% @articles.each do |a| %>
  <%= check_box_tag("doc[article_ids][]", a.id, @doc.articles.include?(a.id), :class => "article_chooser") %> <a id="<%= a.id %>" class="name"><%= a.name %></a><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= select_tag "article_ids[]",options_from_collection_for_select(Article.all.collect{|i| [i.name,i.id]),:multiple => true %>
```

When select multiple options in select list just give article_ids[] , it will store all ids in this array then after you write query how you would store in database. 
If **set the select tag is multiple true** then **you will select multiple options** other wise **you get only one selected value.**

or 
 just read below link
http://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=collection%20select

If you want to give f.select then you must give like this

```
<%= f.collection_select :article_id, Article.all, :id , :name %>
```

Comment: Update: this works, but it doesn't save any of the selections. `<%= select("article", "article_ids[]", Article.where(:page => 1).collect { |i| [i.name, i.id] }, :multiple => true) %>`

Comment: It needs to say `"doc"` instead of `"article"`, but that gives me a no method error for `"article_ids[]"`.